# WinRT Sterling DB crashing when built in Release

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, sterling-db

I'm using sterling DB engine in my winRT metro app(win 8.0). It works great when built in Debug, however when I change build configuration to Release I'm getting an Exception on startup.

UnauthorizedAccessException HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)

at:

```
 public ITableDefinition CreateTableDefinition<T, TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keyFunction) where T : class, new()
    {
        return new TableDefinition<T, TKey>(Driver,
                                            ( key => _Load<T>( typeof( T ), key, new CycleCache() ).Result ),
                                            keyFunction);
    }
```

in BaseDatabaseInstance.

I'm using Sterling.WinRT and Sterling.Core downloaded from codeplex.

Comment: Can you step into that code and find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my database was not fully initialised at the moment. 
But I honestly have no slightest idea what difference did build config made here.